# How to hide an element from DOM using ngif with angular.js and angularmaterial?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angular-material

I'm using angular.js 1.5, and angular material in the frontend to load the DOM with objects from the Database.
In one of the repeaters, I need to check if an object is already included inside another in-scope javascript array. I tried to do it with `Array.indexOf()`, with `Array.forEach`, with a standard for loop looping over each element but it's not happening the way I need it. I must be doing something silly that's preventing the logic to run normally, Ideally a method should return false if the current object exists in the array, or true if it doesn't.

the use case is that the user needs to add item(s) *ObjA* to a list (ObjX.Objs) from another list (Objs)

my front end html code :

```
//here there's an object that contains an array of objects 
<div ng-controller="myFirstController" ng-init="findOne()">
<md-list-item ng-repeat="ObjA in ObjX.Objs" >
</md-list-item>
<div ng-controller="mySecondcontroller" ng-init="find()">
<md-list-item ng-repeat="ObjA in Objs" ng-if="ObjAExists(ObjA, ObjX.Objs)">
</md-list-item>
</div>
</div>
```

Controller method :

```
 $scope.ObjAExists = function(ObjA, list){
     for(var m = 0; m<list.length; m++){
         if(list[m] === ObjA){
             return false;
         }
         else return true;
     }
 }
```

I also tried to match object Id's no difference

```
 $scope.ObjAExists = function(ObjA, list){
     for(var m = 0; m<list.length; m++){
         if(list[m]._id == ObjA._id){
             return false;
         }
         else return true;
     }
 }
```

[Filter skills plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mcj5fjPilXQSyK4UN2nq?p=preview)
There's a plunk I wrote representing the same problem

Comment: Would be better to use a filter. Also need to know if same object references are in both arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're comparing `ObjA` only with first element in list. You should pull `return true;` out of `for` loop.
It will be:

```
$scope.ObjAExists = function(ObjA, list){
 for(var m = 0; m<list.length; m++){
     if(list[m]._id == ObjA._id){
         return false;
     }
 }
 return true;
}
```

* And the name of the method should certainly be ..NotExists

---

Here's [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/WLraEtOASlD2D2DGyWml?p=preview) answering your question from the comments. Pay attention:

- we can't compare by reference because `friend.skills` are not the same objects we have in general `skills list`. That's why compared by `name` property.
- it would be cleaner to use `filter` instead of `ng-if` for filtering "used" skills list

Comment: Did that, anything I do other than writing ng-if= "true", hides all elements in the list of objects ObjA in Objs from the DOM, which means equality evaluation has something wrong in it or else, because I Know that some elements already exist in the Array of objects ObjX.Objs

Comment: @charlietfl it does, it's assigned every time 'ng-repeat' loops  '<md-list-item ng-repeat="ObjA in Objs" ng-if="ObjAExists(ObjA, ObjX.Objs)">'

Comment: @charlietfl - name of the method is backwards :), but loop logic is according to requirement _method should return false if the current object exists in the array_

Comment: @OsamaSalama - try to add some logs. If you could arrange a demo in plunker it would be easier to help you.

Comment: @AlekseyL. I will, I'll rewrite the code with javascript objects in the controller to help you see how's the view is rendered.

Comment: [here's the plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/Mcj5fjPilXQSyK4UN2nq?p=preview)
the purpose here in the lower list that repeats the skills, is to only show skills that is not already in the friend.skills array for all the friends

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
   <li ng-repeat="skill in skills" ng-if="skillExists(skill,friend.skills)">{{skill.name}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

`li` tage can not be use directly under another `li` tag. Because you are using this way `friend.skill` will not be defined and that is the one of the reason why `skillExists` is not working.

Now in your `skillExists` method from my experience I'll suggest that you must not compare two objects directly. Always try use `id` or some `unique attribute` to differentiate each object and that key should be used for object comparison. so here you should use `name` attribute instead of comparing whole object.

Your code

```
if(list[i]===skill){
      return false;
 }
```

Instead of that use

```
if(list[i].name === skill.name){
      return false;
}
```

Here is the link of the working example. https://plnkr.co/edit/mvskLPsTH8eJv6OfPFsB

Comment: thanks, you're correct regarding the availability of friend.skill, it's undefined to the next <li> tag. Also it's not possible to compare each individual skill in friend.skills to skill. The answer provided by Aleksey L. does the job as I need it, which is to filter results from one array based on what's Not included in another array.

Comment: No problem at all. I just told you what was wrong in your code.